# Dynamically binding to a controller method in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

So I'm generating a bunch of markup for a table in a lightning component using D3. I want to make the table headers clickable, and have them invoke an action on the component's JavaScript controller to change the sort order.

What's the easiest way of achieving this? It seems like I need to dynamically create `<aura:outputText>` components for the header cells, but that seems like a [crazy amount of code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) for something so simple when I'd normally just set on `onClick` attribute. Am I better off just finding a way to fire an event or something?

Comment: Maybe helpful? http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2014/09/sorting-visualforce-tables-with.html

Comment: Also seems interesting: https://lightningdart.com/demo.html, it has an example of what you are trying to do although I do not know what D3 is lol

Comment: Register click event to th tag the d3 way and make sure you click event callback is wrapped with `$A.getCallback(function() { ..code..})` and inside your call back fire an event which carries which column name info for the sorting purpose. I haven't tried it personally, I hope this would work for you. Also, if you could post some code we can help you out better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's taken a while, and I've tried all sorts of methods for doing this, but half an hour ago it occurred to me that I might be able to trigger an event to do my bidding. Turns out, it is possible, but it's not pretty (though I still prefer this to adding a component dynamically etc.).

First off we need a custom application event to fire:

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="data"/>
</aura:event>
```

And then we can trigger this via excessively convoluted means:

```
.attr("onClick", column => "$A.getCallback(function(){var e = $A.get('e.c:OutreachReportTableSort'); e.setParam('data', '" + column.field + "'); e.fire(); })()")
```

The first arrow function is a function d3 calls on each data item it's processing, I'm just using it to dynamically insert the field value for that column into the big function string I'm building.

If you don't need a dynamic parameter, then you could just do something like this:

```
.attr("onClick", column => "$A.getCallback(() => {var e = $A.get('e.c:myCustomEvent'); e.fire(); })()")
```

replacing `.attr` with whatever's relevant to the framework/library you're using.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about D3, but I do know how to sort in Lightning. Here's a simple implementation. As you can see, I pretty much just populate a glorified object, and I can sort it generically using a single kind-of-complicated sort function. Here goes:

## Component

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="sortColumn" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="sortAsc" type="Boolean" default="true" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.data.headers}" var="header">
                    <th onclick="{!c.sort}" data-sort-column="{!header.sortColumn}">
                        {!header.label}
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sortColumn==header.sortColumn}">
                            <span>
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sortAsc}">
                                    ▲
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        ▼
                                    </aura:set>
                                </aura:if>
                            </span>
                        </aura:if>
                    </th>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.data.rows}" var="row">
                <tr>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!row.cells}" var="cell">
                        <td>{!cell.text}</td>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

## Component Controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.sortAsc", true);
        component.set("v.sortColumn", "C1");
        component.set(
            "v.data",
            { headers: [
                {  sortColumn: "C1",    label: "Column 1" },
                {  sortColumn: "C2",    label: "Column 2" },
                {  sortColumn: "C3",    label: "Column 3" }
            ],
             rows: [
                 { cells: [
                     { text: "Value 1", value: 1 },
                     { text: "Value 3", value: 3 },
                     { text: "Value 9", value: 9 }
                 ] },
                 { cells: [
                     { text: "Value 7", value: 7 },
                     { text: "Value 4", value: 4 },
                     { text: "Value 2", value: 2 }
                 ] },
                 { cells: [
                     { text: "Value 8", value: 8 },
                     { text: "Value 9", value: 9 },
                     { text: "Value 3", value: 3 }
                 ] }
             ]
            }
        );
    },
    sort: function(component, event, helper) {
        var data = component.get("v.data"),
            sortAsc = component.get("v.sortAsc"),
            sortField = component.get("v.sortColumn");
        data.headers.forEach(
            function (v,i,a) {
                var thisSortField = v.sortColumn;

                if(thisSortField == event.target.dataset.sortColumn) {
                    sortAsc = thisSortField != sortField || !sortAsc;
                    sortField = thisSortField;
                    component.set("v.data.rows", data.rows.sort(
                        function(a, b) {
                            var left = a.cells[i].value,
                                right = b.cells[i].value,
                                t1 = left == right,
                                t2 = (left == null && right != null) || (left < right),
                                result = t1? 0: (sortAsc?-1:1)*(t2?1:-1);
                            return result;
                        }));
                }
            });
        component.set("v.sortColumn", sortField);
        component.set("v.sortAsc", sortAsc);
    }
})
```

The doInit function is just a placeholder--I'd expect you to do your loading algorithm here. The interesting bit is the sort algorithm. It supports any number of columns, and can sort by any data type that JavaScript can naturally compare using the less-than operator.

Notice how I build all of the rows and cells using nothing more than iterators. Assuming your D3 thing can take arbitrarily build elements and transform them, I'm sure you an achieve a similar result.

The point of all this code is that the methods themselves are not dynamic. I simply used a normal HTML-5 dataset attribute to match up the method's target with the appropriate column to sort by. This component is intentionally not styled in any way to minimize the amount of code I had to paste in here, which was already pretty large, but a lot more efficient than using $A.createComponents.

Comment: I like this, but the goal isn't just to sort, it's to do completely superfluous animations of the sort as it happens, and to do that I really need more control over the DOM (hence D3). It is silly doing OTT stuff like animations for most use cases, but for products shiny is important!

Comment: @MattLacey That's a good point. I'll see if I can come up with something.